# totalcountchange event not work with ext mvc

Tags: extjs4

I Create a store like this:

```
Ext.define('App.store.task.STask', {
       extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
       //more other code....
        listeners :{
            totalcountchange :function(){
                console.info('1111');
            }
        }
    });
```

look the code,
totalcountchange not work,and i can't find this event on extjs4 api。i tried many times,but not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event `totalcountchange`.

You can use the event `datachanged`.
You can access and count (`store.data.length`) your store data in the handler function.

See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged

Comment: but in "infinite-scroll-with-filter.js",this demo use it.